# Summary of lists of coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm, tkinter

I need to analyze a list of coordinates. The program should "summarize" the list.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('map.png')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
l = []
x = 0
y = 0

for y in range(im.size[1]):
    for x in range(im.size[0]):
        if sum(rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))) == 0:     
            a = [x, y]
                l.append(a)
```

This generates a list of the coordinates of all black pixels from an image with several black rectangles on a white surface. The output is something like this:

```
[[599, 257], [600, 257], [601, 257], [602, 257], [603, 257], [604, 257], [605, 257], [606, 257], [599, 258], [600, 258], [601, 258], [602, 258], [603, 258], [604, 258], [605, 258], [606, 258], [599, 259], [600, 259], [601, 259], [602, 259], [603, 259], [604, 259], [605, 259], [606, 259], [599, 260], [600, 260], [601, 260], [602, 260], [603, 260], [604, 260], [605, 260], [606, 260], [599, 261], [600, 261], [601, 261], [602, 261], [603, 261], [604, 261], [605, 261], [606, 261], [599, 262], [600, 262], [601, 262], [602, 262], [603, 262], [604, 262], [605, 262], [606, 262], [599, 263], [600, 263], [601, 263], [602, 263], [603, 263], [604, 263], [605, 263], [606, 263], [622, 286], [623, 286], [624, 286], [625, 286], [626, 286], [627, 286], [622, 287], [623, 287], [624, 287], [625, 287], [626, 287], [627, 287], [622, 288], [623, 288], [624, 288], [625, 288], [626, 288], [627, 288], [622, 289], [623, 289], [624, 289], [625, 289], [626, 289], [627, 289], [622, 290], [623, 290], [624, 290], [625, 290], [626, 290], [627, 290], [622, 291], [623, 291], [624, 291], [625, 291], [626, 291], [627, 291]]
```

The "summaries" should be information about the black rectangles. The output should be: [x-coordinate, y-coordinate, length, height] for each rectangle, which requires the coordinates of the origin.

In this case: `[[599, 257, 8, 7], [622, 287, 6, 6]]`

I don't know if I should work with arrays or matrices or something completely different. I'm open to ideas. The important part is to get that information from these kind of images.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Looks like a neat problem, just to clarify on the language by _length_ and _high_ do you mean _width_ and _height_? Also, they don't count the same row/column of the x/y-coordinates? [599, 257, 7, 6] implies 7 • 6 = 42 pixels, but you seem to be covering 56 pixels with that particular group.

Comment: You may want to look up [_floodfill_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). It may be a potential algorithm here.

Comment: The adjective to rectangle is rectangular. I leave to you to look up what you used instead.

Comment: i could not solve the problem yet. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [floodfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), or [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29), or maybe some other approach.

here we will take advantage that we know we are looking for a rectangular shape, aligned with the `x` and `y` axis.

The algorithm scans each given pixel for its four neighbors in the x and y directions, and determines if they are part of an isolated black rectangle; if so, the pixel is added to the component; when no new pixels are found to belong to a component, the next available pixel is used as seed for the next component, and so on.

From the isolated individual components (black rectangles), is is simple to find the bounding box, and represent it as desired.

```
import tkinter as tk


def find_extent(points):
    xmin = min(x for x, _ in points)
    xmax = max(x for x, _ in points)
    ymin = min(y for _, y in points)
    ymax = max(y for _, y in points)
    return(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
    
def get_four_neighbors(point):
    x, y = point
    return (x, y+1), (x, y-1), (x+1, y), (x-1, y)
    
def isolate_components(points):
    """return connected components,
    taking advantage that we are looking for rectangles
    """
    components = []
    points_ = set(tuple(point) for point in points)
    while points_:
        current_comp_head = points_.pop()
        to_visit = [current_comp_head]
        component = []
        while to_visit:
            current = to_visit.pop()
            component.append(current)
            for point in get_four_neighbors(current):
                if point in points_:
                    to_visit.append(point)
                    points_.remove(point)
        components.append(component)
    return components
    
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

points = [[599, 257], [600, 257], [601, 257], [602, 257], [603, 257], [604, 257], [605, 257], [606, 257], [599, 258], [600, 258], [601, 258], [602, 258], [603, 258], [604, 258], [605, 258], [606, 258], [599, 259], [600, 259], [601, 259], [602, 259], [603, 259], [604, 259], [605, 259], [606, 259], [599, 260], [600, 260], [601, 260], [602, 260], [603, 260], [604, 260], [605, 260], [606, 260], [599, 261], [600, 261], [601, 261], [602, 261], [603, 261], [604, 261], [605, 261], [606, 261], [599, 262], [600, 262], [601, 262], [602, 262], [603, 262], [604, 262], [605, 262], [606, 262], [599, 263], [600, 263], [601, 263], [602, 263], [603, 263], [604, 263], [605, 263], [606, 263], [622, 286], [623, 286], [624, 286], [625, 286], [626, 286], [627, 286], [622, 287], [623, 287], [624, 287], [625, 287], [626, 287], [627, 287], [622, 288], [623, 288], [624, 288], [625, 288], [626, 288], [627, 288], [622, 289], [623, 289], [624, 289], [625, 289], [626, 289], [627, 289], [622, 290], [623, 290], [624, 290], [625, 290], [626, 290], [627, 290], [622, 291], [623, 291], [624, 291], [625, 291], [626, 291], [627, 291]]

components = isolate_components(points)

summaries = []
for component in components:
    summaries.append(find_extent(component))
    for x, y in component:
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x, y, outline='blue', fill='blue')
    
for summary in summaries:
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = summary
    print(f'{x0}, {y0}, {x1-x0+1}, {y1-y0+1}')
    canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1+1, y1+1, outline='green', width=2)
        

root.mainloop()
```

#### Output:

```
599, 257, 8, 7
622, 286, 6, 6
```

[image]

*(Cropped screenshot of the canvas)*